# Removing Checked checkbox elements using a function

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Trying to make a to-do list using JavaScript but can't seem to figure out a way to delete the checked checkboxes.

I tried to have the program change the id then delete everything with that new id but that didn't seem to work, maybe I was missing something important not sure but if any of you know a different way of deleting checked checkboxes, I'd appreciate the help.

```js
function add() {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

   var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;


   // creating checkbox element 
   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');



   if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("Input is Empty!");
   } else {
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(checkbox);
   }

   // Assigning the attributes to created checkbox 
   checkbox.type = "checkbox";
   checkbox.name = "name";
   checkbox.value = "value";
   checkbox.id = "checkBox";

   // create label for checkbox 
   var label = document.createElement('label');

   // assigning attributes for the created label tag  
   label.htmlFor = "checkBox";

   // appending the created text to the created label tag   
   label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputValue));

   // appending the checkbox and label to div 
   myDiv.appendChild(checkbox);
   myDiv.appendChild(label);

}

function remove() {
   var doc = document.getElementById("checkBox").checked;
   doc.remove;
}
```

```html
  <h1>To Do List</h1>

  <input type="text" id="myInput">

  <button onclick='add()'>Click me!</button>
  <button onclick="remove()">Delete</button>

  <ul id="myUL">
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </ul>
```

Comment: How about add a class for the checked checkbox. Use css to hide the checkboxes with the class set?

Comment: Or you can attach a handler on the checkbox and hide it when it gets checked.

Comment: `checkbox.id = "checkBox";` should be unique

Comment: The problem is with this line. var doc = document.getElementById("checkBox").checked; This will not return a dom element. Assign unique Ids to the checkbox and then get the reference to the checkbox by using var doc = document.getElementById("checkBox"); Remove doc after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues to your code:

1. You are recycling the `#checkBox` ID. Remember that IDs must be unique within a document. Therefore, you should be generating a unique ID for each label + checkbox pair
2. You are only removing the checkbox element and not the label text, so even if your logic works, the appearance / outcome of your code is not what you want.

A solution will be **wrapping your label text and the checkbox element inside the label**. The advantages of this is that:

- The `<label>` element does not need a `for` attribute, since clicking on the label will automatically check the nested checkbox
- You can use `.closest('label')` to remove the entire label text + checkbox pair, when you hit the delete button

In order to iterate through all the checked checkboxes, you can simply run this selector: `document.querySelector('.checkbox:checked')`. To iterate through this Node collection, you can use `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

Another note: you might want to **return from the function** if there an empty text is provided when a user wants to add a textbox.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
function add() {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

   var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;


   // creating checkbox element 
   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

   if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("Input is Empty!");
      return;
   } else {
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(checkbox);
   }

   // Assigning the attributes to created checkbox 
   checkbox.type = "checkbox";
   checkbox.name = "name";
   checkbox.value = "value";
   checkbox.classList.add("checkbox");

   // create label for checkbox 
   var label = document.createElement('label');
   
   // appending the checkbox and created text to the created label tag   
   label.appendChild(checkbox);
   label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputValue));
   
   // appending label to div
   myDiv.appendChild(label);

}

function remove() {
   const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.closest('label').remove();
   });
}
```

```html
<h1>To Do List</h1>

  <input type="text" id="myInput">

  <button onclick='add()'>Click me!</button>
  <button onclick="remove()">Delete</button>

  <ul id="myUL">
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restructure your html. Create a separate function `createItem()` which 
returns a `<div>` containing `<input>` and text. Give a specific `className` to container `div`.

Inside `remove()` you `querySelectorAll()` to get all items. And use `forEach()` to loop through items and check if the input of item is checked then `remove()` it

**Note:** `id` of the element in whole document should be unique

```js
function createItem(text){
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = 'item'
  container.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" /><span>${text}</span>`
  return container;
}

function add() {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

   var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

   // creating checkbox element 
   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
   if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("Input is Empty!");
   } else {
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(createItem(inputValue));
   }
}

function remove() {
   var doc = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
   doc.forEach(x => {
    if(x.querySelector('input').checked){
      x.remove()
    }
   })
}
```

```html
<h1>To Do List</h1>

  <input type="text" id="myInput">

  <button onclick='add()'>Click me!</button>
  <button onclick="remove()">Delete</button>

  <ul id="myUL">
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a query:

```js
function removeCheckedCheckboxes() {
    const query = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    
    Array.from(query).forEach(element =>
        element.remove()
    );
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <span style="background: red; display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
  <br>
  
  <span style="background: orange; display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
  <br>
  
  <span style="background: yellow; display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>  
  <br>
  
  <span style="background: green; display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
  <br>
  
  <span style="background: blue; display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
  <br>
 
  <span style="background: purple; display: inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span> 
  <br>
  
  <br>
  
  <button onclick="removeCheckedCheckboxes()">
    Remove checked checkboxes
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```